# Spreadsheet stored on Sharepoint needed in Access

Tags: excel, ms-access, sharepoint

I have a spreadsheet that is stored on a SharePoint site and I would like to link to this spreadsheet to create a "live" table in my Access database. When I go to Get external data->Excel->Link to the Data source by creating a linked table, I get an error because the filepath begins with http:. Is there a workaround for this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You cannot link to a web site, or a file sitting on some web site. You need (must) use the windows file networking system for this to work.

You thus could as a workaround download the file local, and then link to the local file.